# Check if no account added in settings then jump to facebook app facebook login in iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook

I integrated facebook with my own app to login, and I integrated with native facebook and code is following. Now whats happening when there is no account added in settings-> facebook or if account added and then user change their password of same account from browser not in settings in both case I want to drag user to login from facebook app in iPhone or if no app exist then I want to jump user to login from browser.
Here is my code.

```
  _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         FB_APP_ID, ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                         nil];

[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:options completion:
 ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
     if (granted)
     {
         NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
         //it will always be the last object with single sign on
         _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];


         ACAccountCredential *facebookCredential = [_facebookAccount credential];
         NSString *accessToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken];
         NSLog(@"Facebook Access Token: %@", accessToken);
         _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];


 _facebookToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken];
         NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",_facebookAccount);

     }
     else
     {

         NSLog(@"%@",e);
         NSLog(@"%d",e.code);}
```

Comment: for that you should use Facebook sdk.There u can specify the priority.

Answer (score 0):

By using Facebook SDK.For changing the priority you can change the behaviour,
     FBSessionLoginBehavior(enum).

```
-(void)loginFacebookWithCompletion:(RTLoginHandler)handler
    {
        // Initialize a session object
        FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        // Set the active session
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        // Open the session
        [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                    FBSessionState status,
                                    NSError *error)
        {
            if(status == FBSessionStateOpen)
            {
               // You get a opened session here
            }

        }];
    }
```